# API to pin locations in google maps for all pending orders

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bing-api

i have an ecommerce web application where i'm integrating google maps, my requirement is to pin all the pending orders in map.

i have locations data store , and each location will fall under a location group , so i want to map these location groups with google maps and show all the pending orders with in the locations of the location group.

Is there any way i can achieve this? any sample references that i can look into?

Comment: I have similar concern but seems no much are helping on this>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587946/show-locations-on-a-map-in-c-sharp-form?noredirect=1#comment58866948_35587946

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Data Layer which allows you to easily map GeoJSON data. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer

If you have your GeoJSON data nested as orders & groups you can use the declarative style rules to change the style or visibility easily.

See the GeoJSON Editor as a starting point for adding points:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geojson/